# Linking the View / Model in Django to a Javascript Front End Framework

Tags: jquery, angularjs, django, backbone.js, reactjs

I'm fluent in Javascript, as well as python and generally familiar with django, but very new with some of these javascript front end frameworks.

I'm a little confused on which tool I should use for the following scenario:

A user has a search query that has several factors, but I want the factors to be adjustable after the query (i.e price slider).

Ideally new results (from the queryset filter in django view) render without refresh.

Another scenario is classic ajax with form submission without refresh required.

I'm considering all the major libraries (jquery, react) as well as frameworks (backbone, angular, ember).

Can all of these accomplish the example I gave? What type of process is this called (data-binding?) and where can I find some good tutorials on wiring up django with whichever framework/library.

Thanks in advance, any input is appreciated.

Comment: You can definitely accomplish this with just jQuery, although it may be cleaner with a more powerful javascript framework like Angular or React. Are you planning on doing a lot more features like this on your site, or just this one?

Comment: For now, I'm only concerned with the search filters and form submission. Later on I might add some additionally functionality. How might I go about accomplishing the search feature function with jQuery/React/Angular?

Comment: Let me suggest some things in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm suggesting the following with your price slider example in mind. Here's an example of how to search users by name with just jQuery.

You'll need an input form for the search query, obviously.

```
<form class="search-form">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.." id="search-name">
    <button class="search-submit">Go!</button>
    <!-- toggleable search options here, including your price slider. -->
</form>
```

Customize the look of this however you want. The important thing here is the user will enter text in the search box, and click "Go!". You'll want to attach a jQuery event to this action, *not* submit as a form because that will reload your page, which you don't want.

```
$(".search-submit").click(function() {
    var url = "/search?name=" + $("#search-name").val();
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            // Dynamically change your page results with more jquery based on data
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert("Something went wrong");
        }
    });
});
```

Next, you need a URL and View to accept this ajax request.

urls.py:

```
from views.py import search
# Search URL
url((r'^search/$', search),
```

views.py:

```
import json
from app.models import User
from django.http import HttpRespons

def search(request):
    # Grab the data
    query = request.GET.get("name", None)
    # Make the query using your backend, the following is just an example
    users = User.objects.filter(name=name)
    # Serialize the objects as necessary
    data = []
    for user in users:
        data.append({
            "name" : user.name,
            "age" : user.age,
            # Other stuff you want from the objects you retrieved.
        })
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data))
```

This closes the loop. When a user enters a search query, the ajax will make a call to your resource, get new results, and I'll leave the dynamic changing of the page to you.

Things to do:
  - some kind of loading "mask" while your query is being fetched. Can be done with jquery and CSS
  - Extra search options. Probably best done as more query strings in your request you make to the server. For example, "/search?name=Jack&age=42".

Comment: thanks this is what I'm looking for! Out of curiosity at what point would implementing backbone/angular or react be meaningful? And what added functionality would they have to the application?

Comment: Angular and other javascript frameworks are a lot more powerful in terms of functionality than jQuery. I wouldn't add those just yet until you really understand them, because they add a ton of overhead to how you build your site. My suggestion is to read about them and see what features they offer, but stick with your current path until you're convinced you need them.